# Modifying size of JFrame with Netbeans visual editor

Tags: java, swing, size

What property I am modifying when when dragging or double click the border of a `JFrame`, or `JDialog` or *similar*, using the visual editor that comes bundle within every Netbeans distribution?

I thing that the IDE is somehow modifying the size attribute inherited from `JComponent` Class. But I see the code generated by the IDE and there is no call to `setSize`... so that let me really wondering if somebody know what is behind.

Comment: The size of the frame *should* initially be set by the components and layouts it contains.  If you 'double click' a `JFrame` border, it will be maximized.  I did not think the `JDialog` behaved that way though.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks for you reply @AndrewThompson, the fact is that i am searching what is happing "of the record" when you set the size of and JFrame or JDialog dragging his border in the visual editor of NetBeans. Try to "double click" the JFrame Border (inside the NetBeans Visual Editor for Swing), and you will see that a new Dialog appers in order to set the Dimensions of the Component. After you put new valid values, if you go an see the source of the code, there is no new lines of codes... kind of strange specially because the JFrame or JDialog size actually changes when you run the App.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when using any `JFrame` or `JDialog` you should use `pack` whereever possible.

Having said that, if you click the "Code" of the "Properties" window for the form, you will see two properties:  "Form Size Policy" and "Designer Size".

Comment: Victor: For reference, you can examine the generated code for each change by clicking the _Source_ button in the _Show Editor Toolbar_ view.

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, I will check out what is the meaning of Form Size Policy and Designer Size. I know that pack makes all the arrangements to properly layout the components within a container. @trashgod, i checked the source code generated magically by the ide, that was the reason of this question after all. Thanks anyway to both!. Anyway.. i want to find what is going on.. what kind of operations or algorithm follow the IDE set in behalf of us in order to set the size.